# How do I change the color of a button that opens a mode using another button?

Tags: button, modal-dialog

(doubt about jquery)
I have a button that opens a modal, and inside the modal I have a button, I would like to know how to change the color of the button that opened the modal when clicking the button inside the modal.
and can not be by id or classes, because I have clones of that button.

Comment: please show some code for us to see where you get stuck. It is required to have some research and effort put in before looking for help. [here is the api that can get you started](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-color.asp)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<button type="button" onclick="" class=""  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#res_calendario">button 1</button>
<button type="button" onclick="" class=""  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#res_calendario">button 2</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="res_calendario" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title text-center" id="myModalLabel">teste</h4>
      </div>
        <button data-dismiss="modal">button 3</button>
      <div class="modal-footer">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: when I click on button 3 I need the color of the button clicked to be changed, I have two buttons that are the same